# Adding external assets to laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, webpack

> Probably old question but **I never tried it before** and couldn't find
>   a solution for it (all i found was samples by scss files)

I am using JavaScript scaffolding as my front-end so all I have in my layout assets as:

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```

Now I have custom assets files that I would like to attach it to my `app.css` and `app.js` file.

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/shards.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="{{ asset('js/shards.min.css') }}" defer></script>
```

This is my `webpack.mix.js` file:

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

## Question

1. How should I add my custom assets to the code above?

Comment: Read this https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mix#vanilla-js

Comment: @AfrazAhmad let say https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mix#plain-css then should I remove my `webpack` default codes or just add this below it?

Comment: add it below the default lines of code

Comment: i'll try........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can add and compile scrips like shown below:**

```
mix.scripts([
'public/js/admin.js',
'public/js/dashboard.js'
], 'public/js/all.js');
```

For more you read official docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mix#vanilla-js)

Comment: it didn't create any new files as `all.css` and `all.js`

Comment: make sure your file paths are correct and you have cleared the config and cached data then try `npm run dev`. `all.css` is located at `public/css/` and `all.js` is at `public/js/`